# XSLT 2.0 Merge 2 timeseries

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

Here's my problem:
I have an input with 2 timeseries .
One is in the "POS"-Tag, the other in the "NEG"-Tag
Values are in the "Qty" attribute.
The desired Output is the two timeseries being netted, "POS-Qty" - "NEG-Qty".

```
<DATUM>2014-04-24T22:00:00<POS><Period xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <TimeInterval v="2014-04-24T22:00Z/2014-04-25T22:00Z"/>
            <Resolution v="PT15M"/>
            <Interval>
                <Pos v="1"/>
                <Qty v="15"/>
            </Interval>
            <Interval>
                <Pos v="2"/>
                <Qty v="6"/>
            </Interval>
            <Interval>
                <Pos v="3"/>
                <Qty v="9"/>
            </Interval>
            <Interval>
                <Pos v="4"/>
                <Qty v="8"/>
            </Interval>
</Period></POS><NEG><Period xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <TimeInterval v="2014-04-24T22:00Z/2014-04-25T22:00Z"/>
            <Resolution v="PT15M"/>
            <Interval>
                <Pos v="1"/>
                <Qty v="23"/>
            </Interval>
            <Interval>
                <Pos v="2"/>
                <Qty v="80"/>
            </Interval>
            <Interval>
                <Pos v="3"/>
                <Qty v="59"/>
            </Interval>
            <Interval>
                <Pos v="4"/>
                <Qty v="2"/>
            </Interval>
</Period></NEG></DATUM>
```

I tried playing around with something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:formatter="com.inubit.ibis.xsltext.Formatter" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="2.0">
      <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
      <xsl:template match="/"><DATA><xsl:for-each select="/DATUM/POS/Period/Interval"><xsl:value-of select="xs:integer(/DATUM/POS/Period/Interval/Qty/@v) - xs:integer(/DATUM/NEG/Period/Interval/Qty/@v)"/></xsl:for-each></DATA>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, that doesn't work - but I don't know how i should aprroach that.

Output should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<DATUM>2014-04-24T22:00:00
  <NET>
    <Period xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>
      <TimeInterval v="2014-04-24T22:00Z/2014-04-25T22:00Z"/> 
        <Resolution v="PT15M"/> 
          <Interval> 
           <Pos v="1"/> 
           <Qty v="-8"/> 
             </Interval> 
          <Interval> 
           <Pos v="2"/> 
           <Qty v="-74"/> 
             </Interval> 
          <Interval> 
           <Pos v="3"/> 
           <Qty v="-50"/>
             <Interval> 
           <Pos v="4"/> 
           <Qty v="6"/> 
             </Interval>
 </NET>
</DATUM>
```

Please note:
There are 96 "Interval"-Elements - in "NEG" and in "POS" - I cut it to 4, to make it easier to read.

Thank You!

Comment: Hi! Can you please give an example of the desired output? That would make it easier to understand.

Comment: `code <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATUM>2014-04-24T22:00:00<NET><Period xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <TimeInterval v="2014-04-24T22:00Z/2014-04-25T22:00Z"/>
            <Resolution v="PT15M"/>
            <Interval>
                <Pos v="1"/>
                <Qty v="-8"/>
            </Interval>
            <Interval>
                <Pos v="2"/>
                <Qty v="-74"/>
            </Interval>
            <Interval>
                <Pos v="3"/>
                <Qty v="-50"/>
            </Interval>`

Comment: Good. I see you are new to StackOverflow, so let me advise you to edit your question and put that example code there.

Comment: Done. Sorry for that...could have thought about that myself...

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for ;) welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 3 as supported by Saxon 9.8 all editions or Altova 2017 and 2018 has an `xsl:merge` instruction you could use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="POS">
        <NET>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </NET>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="POS/Period">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, * except Interval"/>
            <xsl:merge>
                <xsl:merge-source for-each-item="., ../following-sibling::NEG[1]/Period"
                    select="Interval">
                    <xsl:merge-key select="Pos/@v"/>
                </xsl:merge-source>
                <xsl:merge-action>
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Pos"/>
                        <Qty v="{current-merge-group()[1]/Qty/@v - current-merge-group()[2]/Qty/@v}"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:merge-action>
            </xsl:merge>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NEG"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result is

```
<DATUM>2014-04-24T22:00:00<NET>
      <Period xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <TimeInterval v="2014-04-24T22:00Z/2014-04-25T22:00Z"/>
         <Resolution v="PT15M"/>
         <Interval>
            <Pos v="1"/>
            <Qty v="-8"/>
         </Interval>
         <Interval>
            <Pos v="2"/>
            <Qty v="-74"/>
         </Interval>
         <Interval>
            <Pos v="3"/>
            <Qty v="-50"/>
         </Interval>
         <Interval>
            <Pos v="4"/>
            <Qty v="6"/>
         </Interval>
      </Period>
   </NET>
</DATUM>
```

Using XSLT 2 you could use a key to find the other value and substract it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="pos" match="DATUM/NEG/Period/Interval" use="Pos/@v"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="POS">
        <NET>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </NET>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Interval/Qty/@v">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select=". - key('pos', ../../Pos/@v, ancestor::DATUM)/Qty/@v"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NEG"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I only have XSLT 2.0 here.
But thank you! :)

Comment: @Husky-CGN, I have added an XSLT 2 sample.

Comment: Thank You! I'll try to wrap my head around that :)

Comment: it complains at Interval[65] "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the second operand of '-'; Line#: -1; Column#: -1" I'll look, if I find it...

Comment: Are there several `NEG` and `POS` child elements of a `DATUM`? How are they related? By the `TimeInterval` value?

Comment: There is one "NEG" Element, that contains 96 "interval"-Elements. And there is one "POS" Element that also contains 96 "Interval"-Elements. 
For the examples here, I cut the "Interval"-Elements to four of each - POS and NEG, 
because otherwise, it would have gotten really, really long.

Comment: The expression ` key('pos', ../../Pos/@v, ancestor::DATUM)` finds to find a matching `NEG/Interval` using the `Pos/@v` attribute because I assumed that to be unique and to be the key to relate the `Interval` element to each other. The error message suggests there are elements with the same `Pos/@v` inside the `NEG`.

Comment: Figured that yes, and I found it...colleague did his own testing and changed one the "@Pos" values instead of "@Qty"...
And the moment you input the right data, it suddenly works ;)

THANK YOU!!